# Exposing private network ip

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have the following setup:

```
Box A
eth0 - 192.168.1.101
eth1 - 10.10.2.1

Box B
eth0 - 10.10.2.2
```

Box A has internet access through eth0. I want Box B to be visible on the 192.168.1.0/24 network, so I can ssh to it directly from another box, but Box A must also be available.

I thought about creating a virtual ip to eth0 on Box A and then forward all traffic to Box B with

```
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.102

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.2.2
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Also ip forwarding is enabled and Box B has internet access with

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I am by no means a expert in iptables, but isnt it suppose to be like this

"iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.2.2"

Comment: Why not use a router? How are you connecting your other systems?

Comment: The router connects the 192.168.1.0/24 network to the internet, and box A is connected to this network. @Sarge I want to forward all the traffic, not just the ssh port.

Comment: Have you tried `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.102 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.2.2`?  That is, matching the traffic by destination address rather than interface alias?  I don't think you can match an interface alias that way.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks, that also worked. I also added `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` on Box A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by adding a static route on the default gateway in `192.168.1.0/24` network, which would say that all packets to `10.10.2.0/24` network would be routed via `192.168.1.101` node.

Then, you would need to enable IP forwarding on `192.168.1.101`.

Then, you would also need to add route to `192.168.1.0/24` via `10.10.2.1` on Box B.

This way you can use the `10.10.2.x` and `192.168.1.x` addresses in both networks and all traffic would be routed between the networks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a virtual interface as the argument to `-i`.  The trick instead is to use the destination *address*:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.102 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.2.2
```